# Jmeter HTTP Request Response Time too low compared to SoapUI

Tags: jmeter, soapui, performance-testing

We are using Apache JMeter (latest version) for load tests of a high performance API. JMeter response time is too high in comparison to SoapUI (free version). SoapUI gets an average response time of 200 milliseconds while JMeter reports at least 1200 milliseconds for the same API, testing from the same machine.

This affects the calculated throughput in each application. On SoapUI I can get up to 850 tps for said API, no errors. On JMeter I'm getting 190 tps at most, no matter what.

Tests are running with 200 threads, for 120 seconds.

I have already tweaked jvm/jmeter heap mmemory, garbage collector, and so on to no avail. Nothing changes. Can anyone help with this? Thank you.

Edit: Added test setup sample images

[JMeter Thread Group and Test Plan Overall Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWrim.png)

[SoapUI TestSuite and Overall Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ocQg.png)

Edit 2: test results

[Jmeter test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzZPH.png)  1105 ms

[SoapUi test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HY4xH.png)  263 ms

Comment: Give example of your test plan,also are you testing web site or unrelated API calls?

Comment: @user7294900 thank you for your reply

Testing unrelated API calls. The test is simple:

 -  1 thread group, containing 1 HTTP request sampler. It is a post request that sends a small json payload to the API. I run the same test using 200 threads for 60 seconds on both JMeter and SoapUI and get totally different results in terms of throughput and response time.

Comment: *120 seconds, not 60 seconds

Comment: Are you sending payload inside Body data in HTTP request?

Comment: Yes, a very small json payload . Object with a single value array.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of one possible reason: you're running JMeter in GUI mode and [this is not something you should be doing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) as JMeter isn't capable of sending requests fast enough, JMeter's GUI mode is designed for tests development and debugging.

Your images don't tell the full story as JMeter test results are missing. It would be also beneficial to generate a [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) and see the correlation between increasing number of virtual users and response time/throughput.

And last but not the least, JMeter can be executed in [Distributed Mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) and in SoapUI it's available only for [LoadUI Pro](https://www.soapui.org/professional/loadui-pro/)

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T, thank you for your answer. No I'm not running JMeter in GUI mode. Actually I'm running in command line mode, with no listeners active, and also tried running using taurus.

I can post the full results, but for simplicity I'll just write down the numbers:

JMeter gets an average of 1200ms response time for each HTTP Request
SoapUI gets an average of 220ms response time per request

Comment: Distributed mode would be helpful   if I could get same results with a small load or small number of VUs / threads. But the problem is even with a small number of VUs/Threads, i get the same slow response time from jmeter, which I cannot understand why.

Same machine, same jvm settings, same connection, doing multiple sequential tests for comparison and getting always same results.

Comment: I have just posted some results which show the huge difference in response time.